# Reading the excel and restructuring the multi-index headers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, group-by, multi-index

I have an excel with the below format:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcEuf.png)

I've read the file into a dataframe with the below code:

```
df= pd.read_excel(exp_path, skiprows=21, header=[0,1])

df = df.drop(columns=df.columns[0], axis=1)
```

After this the df looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbebn.png)

I'm trying to convert to the following structure:

```
    Column     Row              Sample Size Incidence Average
0    18-24   Strongly Disagree   66          20        33
1    25-34   Strongly Disagree   99          30        33
2    35-46   Strongly Disagree   66          20        33
...
```

Thanks in advance for any help guys!!

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.